# how to get access token sharepoint 2013 in java

Tags: java, sharepoint

This is the sample given by microsoft.How I will get access token and put into that respective java code to create folder in sharepoint server location.Please provide some idea.

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/web/lists");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of this project i've created. It provides you most common operations (sill working on it to create a full implementation of the rest api). It has a helper class where you can see the logic behind how to get a sharepoint auth token to call rest api actions.

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java

Answer (score -1):

You can look at [JShare](http://www.independentsoft.com/jshare) . It is Java API for Microsoft SharePoint Server and SharePoint Online (Office 365). The API cares about authentication and access token and you do not need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Hi, but it's a beta version , have you any other suggestion ?

Comment: using binding provider I am able to do authentication,but while accessing getListItems of sharepoint i got error message " See stacktrace.javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.".Can you please give any idea??

Comment: Hi Chintamani.  I have called azure and got access token but when call sharepoint online rest API using access token am getting following error {"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."} . Do you have any idea?